# Which iPhone SDK should I use?

Tags: iphone, sdk

I have little knowledge about how to make application to compatible to a device.

I have iPhone SDK 4.0 and want my app to run on iOS 2.0 or later.

I have read that set only the iPhone OS Deployment Target to 2.0 and use only those API methods which are common after 2.0.

Is it enough?

or do I have to use another (lower) SDK?

or do I have to do something more...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always be developing with the latest SDK.  You can set this in your project's properties under "Base SDK" in the "Architectures" section of your project's settings (right click on the project in the organizer, and go to "Get Info").

However, to make sure that your app runs on older devices, you would do this by setting the "iOS Deployment Target" to iOS 3.0 under the "Deployment" section of the project's settings.

For the record, I said version 3.0 above because that's the lowest possible supported version that I see in my Xcode.  I don't think it's possible to target 2.0 devices anymore.

Comment: +1 Re 2.0 support in Xcode, it's probably because Apple themselves have already EOL'd iOS 2.0.

Comment: +1 thanks for ans.
BUT  
I have iPhone SDK 4.0 and here the iPhone OS Deployment Target is ranging from 2.0 to 4.0...
means my app will run on ios 2.0 or above devices?

Comment: @Online, there are hardly any iOS 2.0 devices out in the wild anymore.  Targeting for 2.0 will greatly reduce the amount of useful new things that were added in 3.0 & 4.0, and still make your app available to the vast majority of people surfing the app store.

Comment: after ans given by WaiLam ,i googled and found somewhere that apple anly accept projects made on last 2 versions of SDK is it true?

Comment: @Online, nope, they just approved my company's app, which only supports OS 4.1 or better.

Answer (score 1):

The newest Sdk. Apple may not accept the Sdk create by old Sdk.

You can target your min required version os for your App even you are using latest version Sdk.

Comment: @WaiLam--after your answer i googled and found somewhere that apple anly accept projects made on last 2 versions of SDK is it true?

Comment: Don't know exactly. But, most of the developer will use lastest SDK. I don't think a developer will use a very old SDK to develop a apps now.